# Intermediary Bootstrap Grid Classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm designing a layout that will serve more like an individual dashboard for registered users. I made it simple, with a basic 2-column grid, one for the sidebar and one for the main content.

Because, like, 80% of the site usage will happen in a separated subsytem, accessed in a chrome-less window (that doesn't matter for the moment), there's not really much content for the right column, the main body.

So I would like to know if it's possible to make the sidebar a bit larger than the current **col-md-2** (pairing with **col-md-10**), but the next level I'm aware of, **col-md-3** is too large for a simple sidebar.

Is there a mid-term or an intermediary class for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not.

However, I've run into this situation a number of times and played with margins to get the size I needed. For example, If you changed col-md-10 to col-md-9 and then did a negative margin on the div inside col-md-2 you could extend your content outside of the grid structure. If done correctly, you wont have any problems. Keep in mind that the margin will need to be adjusted at all media queries. Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Guess I won't touch it then because deal with all *media queries* would be an herculean task for such small (and personal) preference. Thank you